# Go: i/o timeout reading a request proxied by AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, networking, timeout, amazon-elb

We have a pretty standard API server written in Go. The http handler unmarshals the request body (JSON) into a protobuf struct, and sending it off to be processed.

The service is deployed as ECS containers on AWS, fronted by ALB. The service has a pretty high request volume, and we observed that about 0.2% requests fail with messages like this:

```
read tcp $ECS_CONTAINER_IP:$PORT->$REMOTE_IP:$REMOTE_RANDOM_PORT: i/o timeout
```

We tracked it down that the error is returned from jsonpb.Unmarshal method. Our tracing tells us that all these i/o timeout requests take 5s.

Within the container, we did `ss -t | wc -l` to see in flight requests, and the number is quite reasonable (about 200-300ish, which is far lower than the no-file ulimit).

Some quick awk/sort/uniq tells us that the number of inflight requests coming from the ALBs are roughly balanced.

Any idea how do we go on from here?